# Knockout + draggable/droppable extensions is giving me a stuck cursor?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to change the cursor of a dragged element with the standard approach:

```
$(element).draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                revertDuration: 0,
                cursor: "move"
});
```

however whenever an element is "dropped" successfully (set > folder in the fiddle), the cursor "sticks".  I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/50/

To reproduce, just drag the set over into the folder and see how the cursor doesn't revert.  I'm in chrome if it matters.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

UPDATE: I can fix it by adding the following css:

```
#container {
    cursor: default;
}
```

It still strikes me as odd that the container element is getting set to `cursor: move`.  Any insight here would be fantastic as my solution feels awfully hackish.

UPDATE 2: My solution works in the fiddle but not in production - it seems like all parent elements get set to `"cursor: move"`.  Back to scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give time for the UI to update itself. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/PTSkR/51/

```
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('#container').isotope('remove', ui.draggable);
        }, 0);
```

Comment: @SB2055 - I am by no means an expert, but it likely has something to do with cascading subscribe events. One event triggers another that triggers another and another... That value "throttles" the eventing, allowing things to "catch up" and stop the cascade.

Comment: Once dragging is completed ui script still need to update certain things, one of them is removing 'cursor: move' from the body element :). And because you removed draggable element, script probably had error while accessing it and stooped executing. By adding setTimeout, you are allowing code to finish execution. Scheduler will be able to run that code immediately after current execution thread completes it's work.